# cannot follow that tutorial

Tags: objective-c

i tried to follow this tutorial:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-FK1TrpUng&feature=related
 around 00:39:00.

Theres a counter which recognizes every switch to the second view controller and counts it.
The number of view switches should be shown on the second view controller.
But it doesn't work, thats the code:
Test2ViewController.h

```
 @interface Test2ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {

    UINavigationController *navController;
    Test21ViewController *test21View;
    NSString *text;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;



}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textField1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navController;
@property (copy) NSString *text;


-(IBAction)pushViewController:(id)sender;
@end
```

Test2ViewController.m:

#import "Test2ViewController.h"
    #import "Test21ViewController.h"

```
@implementation Test2ViewController

@synthesize textField1, navController, text;


-(IBAction)pushViewController:(id)sender {
    static int count = 1;
    Test21ViewController *test21ViewController = [[Test21ViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:test21ViewController animated:YES];   
    test21ViewController.label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pushed %d", count];
    count++;
}
```

Test21ViewController.h:

```
@interface Test21ViewController : UIViewController {
    UINavigationController *navController;
    NSString *label;
    IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
    UITextField *tF1;


}

@property (copy) NSString *label;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navController;

@property(nonatomic,retain)UITextField *tF1;
-(IBAction)feldeingabe:(id)Sender;
@end
```

Test21ViewController.m:

```
@implementation Test21ViewController
@synthesize label;


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    textLabel.text = label;


}
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work?
Thanks in advance

Code for the second question:

```
static int count = 1;
    Test2ViewController *test2ViewController;  
    test2ViewController.label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pushed %d !!!!!", count];
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    count++;
```

CURRENT CODE:

```
#import "Test21ViewController.h"

@implementation Test21ViewController
@synthesize navController, text, parentView;




-(IBAction)pushViewController2:(id)sender {
    Test2ViewController *test2ViewController;
    static int count = 1;
    test2ViewController.parentView = self;

    test2ViewController.label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pushed %d !!!!!", count];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:test2ViewController animated:YES];    count++;

}
```

Comment: in IB i have one button linked with IBAction pushviewcontroller on the first VC, on the second i have a label, linked with "textlabel"

Comment: What is the exact problem you are getting ? explain in brief don't post only codes it is not too worth.

Comment: Sorry, i filled some text in that label, via IB, but when i try to run that app, the label doesn't appear. I try to hand over a string to another class and found that tutorial. Actually, the label on VC" should show sth like: Pushed 1, or Pushed 2 etc, but it simply doesn't appear. Without the code, it does..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second problem (passing a string from child to parent);

Test2ViewController.h

```
@interface Test2ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    NSString *receiverPropertyFromChild;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *receiverPropertyFromChild;
```

Test2ViewController.m:

```
-(IBAction)pushViewController:(id)sender {
    static int count = 1;
    Test21ViewController *test21ViewController = [[Test21ViewController alloc] init];   
    test21ViewController.label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pushed %d", count];
    test21ViewController.parentView = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:test21ViewController animated:YES];
    count++;
}
```

Test21ViewController.h:

```
@class Test2ViewController;

@interface Test21ViewController : UIViewController {
  Test2ViewController *parentView;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) Test2ViewController *parentView;
```

Test21ViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)goToTest2ViewController:(id)sender {
    parentView.receiverPropertyFromChild = @"the text you want to pass";
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    count++;    
}
```

Comment: Hum shouldn't i be able to show the value of receiverPropertyFromChild via nslog? I added this code to the viewdidload method on first view controller:  NSString *mystring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", receiverPropertyFromChild];

 NSLog (mystring); but it does only show: 0 :x

Comment: Your viewDidLoad method wont run if you popViewController:'ed out to it. Try it in viewWillAppear or somewhere more suited for it, like a button click action handler.

Comment: i tired to use an IBAction for it, like this: -(IBAction)show:(id)sender {
 
 NSString *mystring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", receiverPropertyFromChild];
 [textLabel setText: mystring];
}  //doenst't work, am i able to format a string like this?

Comment: hum well, using that ibaction, the label gets filled with the number: 16468  Why?^^

Comment: btw, the transfer of that string worked: 2011-03-17 17:21:09.880 Test2[14446:207] Value:(null)
2011-03-17 17:21:21.533 Test2[14446:207] Value:test

Comment: unfortunately i don't have enough reputation to vote up :( otherwise i would do it.

Answer (score 0):

can you try:

```
Test21ViewController *test21ViewController = [[Test21ViewController alloc] init];  
test21ViewController.label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pushed %d", count];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:test21ViewController animated:YES];
```

I swapped the last two lines. It could be that you are setting the label after viewDidLoad has already been called, thus not setting the value in the label.

That said, it is better to pass the string as an init parameter, not as a property and then set in viewDidLoad.

edit:

To set it as init parameter, you need to create a new init method to accept that parameter.

```
- (id) initWithString:(NSString *)labelParam {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    this.label = labelParam;
  }
  return self;
}
```

Comment: hum another problem, now i want to try the other way around. i want to dismiss the second viewcontroller and give a value to a label on the first viewcontroller. It works with creating a new firstViewcontroller, but as soon as i want to dismiss the second one via "popViewController", the app crashes. I gonna add the code above. Again: it works when i use that code:  Test2ViewController *test2ViewController = [[Test2ViewController alloc] init];  
but unfortunately, it creates a new version of my first viewcontroller.

Comment: You should not have to recreate your first view controller. You just need to keep a pointer on the second view controller that points to your first view controller. For example, before the after setting your label and before `pushViewController:`, assign `test21ViewController.parentView = self;`, then use that pointer to pass your string back.

Comment: Hm i get that warning: Request for member 'parentView' in something not a structure or union

Comment: parentView should be an assign property. You have to declare and synthesize parentView.

Comment: hum obviously i don't mage to set u that property properly, Test21ViewController.h:   @property (nonatomic, assign) Test2ViewController *parentView;
It's my first project,  don't know, wether i'm able to set these pointers right.

Comment: well the problem is, that i get a warning. that code is placed in the header file of my second view controller, i get that warning: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'Test2ViewController' 

Test2ViewController is the first VC, Test21ViewController is the second one

Comment: I think you forgot to import Test2ViewController.h in Test21ViewController.h

Comment: no, i did import the other header file, ah sorry, i set an import of that header file in the Test2ViewControler.m file

Comment: okay, now i still have the problem, that my app crashes as soon as i want to move back to the first view controller. perhaps i misunderstood your advises, i gonna show the current code in my first post. At least, there are no warnings anymore^^

Comment: Can you try using a forward class reference instead of an import? `@class Test2ViewController;`

Comment: hm how does that work? I never tried using anything else than an import.

Comment: It tells the compiler that there will be a class with that name provided during runtime, and not to worry about its existence during compile time. It is used to avoid cyclic dependencies.

Comment: and where do i have to add that @class Test2ViewController; ? in my header files? so i have to delete #import "Test2ViewController.h" and to add @class Test2ViewController;?

Comment: You have to add it in Test21ViewController.h. Then you have to import Test2ViewController.h in Test21ViewController.m.

Comment: ah okay, im going to use that in the future. I furthermore tried to find the mistake in my code above, but i can't simply make it work. Perhaps the pointer is wrong, it's the only thing the app doesn't accept :/

Comment: Wait, I just noticed that the code you posted is from Test21ViewController.m, is that right? You should use popViewController to move from Test21ViewController to Test2ViewController.

Comment: well, i did that too, but i don't manage to fill that label on VC 1 with the string from VC2

Comment: thats works without any problems: -(IBAction)pushViewController2:(id)sender {
 Test2ViewController *test2ViewController;
 static int count = 1;
 //test2ViewController.parentView = self;

// parentView.label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pushed %d !!!!!", count];
 count++;
 [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; But as soon as i want to give that string to vc 1, the app crashes. I try to use the init parameter, but that wouldn't change anything now right?